# You appear to be blindly approving every edit you see ... not

Tags: discussion

I was bashed with this. The reason:

> For example, this edit should not have been approved:
>   [link to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8491815)

But why? What is wrong with this edit, please?

And I do not *blindly approve*, but I do skip edits of questions in areas where I don't have a competence.

Comment: `implement` is not a code keyword. I would have rejected the whole edit as "no improvement" anyway ...

Comment: Users that edit posts by doing nothing but adding back-ticks or [kbd] markup is a bit of a plague at SO.  It gets especially bad when they add them randomly, like this guy did.  Another user stepped in and corrected the mistake, the likely reason you got "bashed".  Ideally you'd have noticed this yourself and made the correction.  Or rejected the edit since it didn't actually improve the post.  You would not have had to look at the reminder.

Comment: There's also the mis-indentation that nobody managed to rectify.

Comment: I don't know about "blindly approving", but I find it extremely hard to believe that you've been through hundreds of edit suggestions (including skipped ones) and not found a *single* edit that objectively should have been rejected regardless of your domain knowledge. [This audit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8491061) from the last 24 hours could *easily* have been your first rejection, but somehow you managed to blow it anyway.

Comment: `What's` wrong *with* **using** `code emphasis` on thngis *that* aren't `code`?

Comment: I politely put a question ans ask for opinions and get voted down. What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @David: OK, that's it. I missed that.

Comment: @Hans: I would be happy to reject those kbd markups only, but I thought that was bad behaviour. After all, they are not wrong.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Which is better `Because` it's `not` code, or **Because** it's **not** code? Or even *Because* it's *not* code?

Comment: @BoltClock: I could, I do recall that edit which seemed weird. However, I didn't understand the question, so I skipped.

Comment: You didn't Skip, you failed the audit. Skip doesn't fail.

Comment: @Gustav The review mention by BoltClock show you **approved** what you should have obviously rejected as **spam or vandalism**

Comment: Are you by chance confusing the "Approve" and "Skip" buttons? You did not skip the audit linked by BoltClock, you approved it. Which makes it seem like _you appear to be blindly approving every edit you see..._

Comment: @l4mpi: I don't blindly approve but I skip a lot. This time I made a mistake, but can't we all do that? Isn't that why more than one has to approve an edit?

Comment: @David: Spam? What element of that edit indicated spam, please?

Comment: Spam or vandalism. It's one of the rejection reasons. If you'd even tried to reject an edit, you'd have known.

Comment: @gustav  spam or **vandalism** This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is **deliberately destructive. **

Comment: We can see your reviews from your profile. I agree with the determination that you blindly approve. Looking at about a dozen of your reviews, there are three which should have been dealt with differently. Yes, others agree with you on those, but that's not the point. Have a look at this question, where you approved the tag removal. Then see how much should have been edited for that tag removal to be acceptable: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30892020/1927206

Comment: @David: So it's vandalism, not spam? I see no promotion of a product or service.

Comment: @gustav. Yes that close reason is for vandalism **or** spam. It is not spam but is clearly vandalism

Comment: @Gustav David is quoting the "spam/vandilism" reject reason, in reference to [the audit BoltClock referenced](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8491061), which is clearly vandalism. (Not the edit linked in your post, which is not vandalism.)

Comment: OK, I thought it specifically referred to that edit. Thanks to all for the clarification - though I still don't get the vote Down. Nevermind. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: The downvotes are likely an expression of disagreement with your assertion that you do not blindly approve.

Comment: @BoltClock there was also some `...`'s in the post.  I fixed the indentation and remove the `...`'s

Comment: @Gustav After reading your question, the failed audit BoltClock linked to and seeing some of your other review results, I have to say it simply looks like you are either "blindly approving every edit you see" or you don't know how to review to a good standard. You seem to think you've skipped when you've in fact approved, etc. The failed audit BoltClock linked to - why approve such an edit? The additions are just nonsense. Please, take more care with reviews, and understand you are affecting other users posts, suggested edits, and affecting their time.

Answer (score 15):

I was going to comment, but my comment simply didn't fit with formatting, so let's go over some of your recent reviews:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8491821 - either should have been "Reject and Edit", or "Edit and Approve"; either way, it needed to be edited, and you could reject or approve depending on how generous you were feeling.  Pervasive use of "i" instead of "I" wasn't fixed, variables such as `sum(netvalue), sum(vatvalue), sum(grosvalue), vatrate` *could* have been put in code tags.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8490349 - again, this needed to be edited.  Why would you leave that giant block of bold text at the end of the question?  "Regards, George" should also have been removed.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8489429 - Reject.  You approved the removal of the fact that they're using a textview.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8491061 - Reject for vandalism.  That's not even a coherent edit.

And that's just in your first page of reviews; I don't feel like going through 11 more pages of approvals, but given how many are wrong on the first page, I have to assume there's more reviews just like these, which is what people are trying to point out.

Comment: `I don't feel like going through 11 more pages of approvals` - I lied, and on page 2, I found where you (and two others) [approved an edit for spam](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8477400).  Not looking so good.

Comment: Which everyone is now flagging as spam, yes?

Comment: @BillWoodger - not quickly enough. I nuked it.

Comment: @ChrisF - not before someone [rejected my flag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297336/spam-flag-for-product-known-for-being-spammed-on-so-rejected-what-gives) :P

Comment: @ChrisF and dismissed my spam flag as not helpful?

Comment: @BillWoodger - nope. I didn't process any flags on that. If anything my flagging as spam (to feed the system) would have approved your flags.

Comment: @ChrisF I didn't really think it was you, but it was someone (or some thing). New user, straight to new answer on 74-year-old-question, not seen again. Seems sometimes spam not so easy to spot. Again, good shot LBT.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables That was me... I am ashamed.  Though I have learned more about spotting spam now.   Got temp banned for it actually.