# Spam flag for product known for being spammed on Stack Overflow rejected, what gives?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam, specific-answer

Consider [an answer to *Corrupt Form - Rescue or Remake?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324131/corrupt-form-rescue-or-remake/30891100#30891100).

Unless I'm completely mistaking this product for something else, I'm almost positive that the "MS Access Repair tool" has had a history of being spammed on this site, and when I flagged this answer just now, it got rejected by a moderator.

Am I completely mis-remembering this product for something else, or is this actually spam?

Comment: It's very probably spam, but not obvious enough? I can imagine in the "spam flag" queue for mods most are so obviously terrrible that this stands out as being OK.

Comment: If it is actually spam and the mod was wrong, the spammers that did it originally [may be trying to bring it back through SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22MS+Access+Repair+tool%22+is%3Aa) as both answers (that one and another one) talking about it are to _old_ and otherwise inactive questions, both answers by brand new users... Probably something to keep an eye on, even if the mods don't think it's spam at the moment.

Comment: @Kendra - yup, [that's the same one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242102/access-vba-assigning-a-value-to-duplicate-records/30915776#30915776).  Good catch.  Let's see if this flag gets rejected too...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I wasn't aware of the history for the "MS Access Repair tool" (or at least if I was - I'd forgotten about it), so I declined the flag as the first paragraph:

> If you are facing corruption issue in your access file then you can try using the Compact and Repair feature of MS Access. It repairs corrupt database and makes it accessible for database users. Other than this you can also use import feature of MS Access that helps database users to import their corrupt database to a new database file.

Looks like an attempted answer - and the following paragraph (which I won't post) - read to me as "but if that doesn't work - you *could* try XYZ" -- which could well for all I know be a valid solution.

After a chat with other mods - the issue you were flagging for has been handled anyway. Sorry about that.

Comment: For context, this is the spam ring behind these posts: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269821/failed-a-tricky-review-question-not-sure-how-to-proceed . They always promote file repair tools, often using other accounts to seed off-topic questions that they can post their spam to. The first few paragraphs will be reasonable-sounding text (sometimes plagiarized from other answers or sites), followed by an ad for their tools. They're one of our more tricky spammers to deal with.

Comment: I was also declined. After LBT's comment on the other post, I followed the link to the user, reputation of 1, looked at the time they joined, last time active, time of answer. Every time I have seen someone arrive, immediately post an *answer* and then disappear, it has been spam. Before that, I was 50/50 on the post being spam (not knowing the history). Having confirmed, I flagged it, and advertised it for others to flag as spam. I don't mind, it's happened before, and will happen again. If you prick us, do we not abend?

Comment: Maybe mods need a wiki where known spam patterns should be posted.

Comment: I'm not sure how you could have considered this "OK" -- tools for repairing/decrypting/unlocking MS office files are completely off-topic.  (Despite the fact that it's kinda related to the question, and the question itself is not completely off-topic, the answer has zilch to do with programming).  So even when declining the spam flag, you still should have deleted the answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt: When programming Access databases, I regret to say from much painful personal experience that data recovery/corruption reversal tools *may well be essential to a developer's toolkit*. Dealing with MDB/ACCDB corruption potential is something every Access developer must do, although generally experienced devs manage to prevent nearly all corruption, rather than fixing it after the fact. Still, it's the inexperienced ones we're here for, no?

Comment: @NathanTuggy: And OS-level backup tools are an essential part of a developer's toolkit also.  But they aren't development tools.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Those are in no way specific to any given development environment, or to development at all: they're completely orthogonal and choice of them does not interact with any programming choices. Tools (and procedures) for fixing Access corruption? Yeah, those actually *are*, and do.