# Why am I temporarily banned from suggesting edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, edit-ban

I have looked through Meta for an answer to this and it seems like every time this question is asked the answer is because the user had a high number of rejected edits.

I have reviewed my edit history and out of my last 60 suggested edits only 2 have been rejected. Overall, I've had 94 edit suggestions approved, and 6 edit suggestions rejected.  I feel like I have been doing a good job with my editing.  Is there something I am missing for what caused my ban?

Comment: The fact you [edited a spam post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8477400) might have something to do with it. Moderators recently received the ability to manually ban editors from suggesting edits, so that's most probably what happened here. A lot of edit reviewers don't properly reject bad edits, so they don't learn what they're doing is wrong.

Comment: @Kendra wasn't that post just on another meta question?  Or at least a comment?

Comment: Wow, honestly? Perhaps you're actually in league with the spammer?  Isn't that right... ***spammer?***

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yes.  It was brought up in the context of the reviewer who inappropriately approved it.

Comment: @ryanyuyu The only way I knew about it was looking at it on that [comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297314/you-appear-to-be-blindly-approving-every-edit-you-see-not#comment208911_297332), honestly.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297314/3001761

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I temporarily suspended your editing privileges because of [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8477400), where you edited obvious spam instead of flagging it.

When you make edits like that on low-quality posts, you invalidate "not an answer" or "very low quality" flags on those posts and can cause spam and other content to live on the site. You need to pay more attention to what you're editing.

Unfortunately, I didn't have a good way of notifying you of this specific case, so it's a good thing you asked.

Comment: For future reference, if someone comes across that post for the first time ever, what is a dead give away that it was spam?  It has come to light that a lot of people have seen spam from MS access recovery software, but that was the first time I had ever seen that and it seemed like a properly constructed answer.

Comment: @Newd - If the first post by a new user contains a link to a commercial product, be very suspicious of it. The language "I would like to suggest MDB Repair Kit software here to repair corrupt .mdb and .accdb files. This advance repair solution provides perfect recovery and restoring of access database with all queries, table’s data and objects." provides the remaining evidence that this is an ad.

Comment: I definitely was wary of it, though I didn't really think spam.  I just hated how the person answered with words like `Perfect` and tried to think of ways to leave a comment not to answer with certainties.  Though in the end I couldn't think of a nice way to put that and edited and left.   Is there any reason why the user can't just be notified in cases like this?  It seems a little harsh to receive a ban on something that was approved by three other higher rep SO members.

Comment: Let's just say the people who approved that edit will not be doing so for a while, either.

Comment: And how long am I banned for?

Comment: @Newd - Because you got the message here, and your other recent edits look fine, I've lifted the edit ban.

Comment: Thank you.  In your answer you mentioned `I didn't have a good way of notifying you of this specific case`.  Is there normally a way or is there a way that I can make myself contactable in the future?

Comment: @Newd - No, that's more a shortcoming of the current edit banning system. They only recently added the manual bans: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252991/135615 and we currently can't provide specific reasons to users why they're banned. For review bans, we can, and that's helpful to educate people about stuff like this in a private manner. Could be worth a feature request at some point.

Comment: _I definitely was wary of it, though I didn't really think spam._ It's certainly less obvious that someone screaming a phone number 500 times. That one reads like a fake 5 star review.

Comment: @BSMP It definitely seemed strange, but the first half is actually great troubleshooting so I just kind of chalked it up to a language barrier or something and proceeded to clean it up.  At least I know what to look for in the future.  And Like I said I just really wish there was a better system then just banning someone, a warning or something perhaps.

Comment: I gotcha. The "screaming a phone number" part was supposed to be funny.

Comment: @BradLarson how long am I banned? same here

Comment: @RaviMakwana - 4 days. You introduced a series of unnecessary formatting on non-code words that led to multiple edit rejections by the community. This triggered an automatic system-imposed ban on edits. I'd recommend reviewing why these were rejected before suggesting additional edits.