# Suggestion edits, reviews banned for incorrect reason

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I recently got banned temporary (for short time), for leaving incorrect reviews.

[image]

However I didn't see anything wrong I did in ref link given, in Banned Message:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8853556

Original post contains FB Link for promotion and suggested post has removed that link, which is correct.

have I done anything wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right, where to begin.

The edit itself was dubious in the extreme, just formatting and the removal of a link. There was no attempt to improve the content at all.

Then we look at the original question and realise that it was a spam answer. The fact that the user has been deleted is relevant here.

The phrase "polishing a turd" comes to mind.

The correct action should have been to reject the edit and then go to the post and flag it as spam.

Had you done this the post would have been deleted in short order.

Comment: Understood, will keep in mind ahead!

Comment: (*Enters conversation with tail between legs...*) As the submitter of the dubious edit, I understand now that edits invalidate previously submitted flags (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297351/why-am-i-temporarily-banned-from-suggesting-edits), so submitting the edit was not only unnecessary, it was detrimental. Can we talk about why it was considered *spam*, though? "Not an answer" or "low quality" I could see, but I don't understand why was this determined to be spam.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang - the user's account had been deleted. The link was just placed randomly in the "answer". I suspect that had I checked the content would have been copied from somewhere else too.