# Editing Ban, But Few Rejected Edits?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I went to edit a user's post on SO yesterday, and received this message:

> You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits - please review your edit history.

But when I review my editing history, I don't find many rejected edits. What rejected edits I do see are most often:

> Community♦ reviewed this some day: Reject
>
> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

[This meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277893/edit-ban-because-of-community-rejections) addresses Community rejections, and clarifies that these rejections **do not contribute to an editing ban.** If that's the case, why am I banned?

Comment: The lesson here is don't edit crap.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think your edit that was mentioned in this meta question is why: [Suggestion edits, reviews banned for incorrect reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299696/suggestion-edits-reviews-banned-for-incorrect-reason)

According to the answer on that question, you edited an answer that was actually just spam.

---

Additional info from [Kendra](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2607247/kendra)'s comment:

> Recently, Moderators received the ability to temporarily suspend users from suggesting edits- In the case of editing a spam post, I believe they find that bad enough to warrant a temporary ban from just one bad edit. See this [extremely similar situation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297351/why-am-i-temporarily-banned-from-suggesting-edits) for more info on that.

Comment: OK -- I understand now that I ought not to have bothered editing something of such low quality. But just to clarify: was it that single bad edit that resulted in an editing ban?

Comment: You'll have to ask the mod. I just happened to remember your gravatar and username from the other question.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang Recently, Moderators received the ability to temporarily suspend users from suggesting edits- In the case of editing a spam post, I believe they find that bad enough to warrant a temporary ban from just one bad edit. See [this extremely similar situation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297351/why-am-i-temporarily-banned-from-suggesting-edits) for more info on that.

Comment: @Kendra Super, thanks for the info! Would you care to offer that info as an answer on this question so that I can accept it?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang I think BSMP's answer more directly answers your question. My information was really just bonus info. I think it'd be better overall for BSMP to edit some of that information into their answer, really. Glad the info helped you though.

Comment: @Kendra - Edited it in. If it is more appropriate to convert this answer to a Community Wiki, please do so.