# What happens to close flags after an edit has occurred?

Tags: support, flags

If I flag a question as being *Unclear of what they were asking* as well as multiple other people for that matter, but the question has not been closed, and the OP edits their question to be a good question that **is clear** now, does the question stay flagged or what happens to the flags on that question?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344740/what-happens-if-a-question-gets-edited-after-getting-flagged-for-being-unclear

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The flag stays until either:

- the question is closed,
- the flag gracefully ages away after two weeks, or
- you retract your close vote (which requires the "Vote to Close" privilege).

You did the right thing in that you flagged content *as you saw it at the time*.  If there are still sufficient issues with it, it will likely accrue more flags and close votes, which indicates that the system is still doing what it should be.

Comment: O rly? According to the accepted answer by @brad-larson on [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297351/why-am-i-temporarily-banned-from-suggesting-edits), edits *"invalidate 'not an answer' or 'very low quality' flags"*. Does that mean that only these types of flags are affected by edits, but not others?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang:  Likely, yes. Even more so considering that the flags in that particular example are not entirely applicable to this one, as they're asking about a question, not an answer.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang only if they are done trough the Low Quality Review Queue, organic edits don't affect NAA/VLQ flags on answers.