# What happens to a closed question when it is edited?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, specific-question, reopen-closed

I wanted to modify elements in a list today, but not use a Python list comprehension because the modifications were more complex than I was comfortable coding with a list comprehension. I also did not want to create a new list as my list will have several hundred thousand objects and I have lots of other pieces in memory. Thus I Googled for 'python list replace element' and came across this [closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582138/finding-and-replacing-elements-in-a-list-python).

I was intrigued by the close reason (closed as not a real question). I thought the question should not be closed so I edited it to at least add an example.

I did this because I can't vote to reopen and it seems from asking [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326853/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-marked-dupes-when-a-user-cannot-vote-to-reopen-an) the only way I can get a question considered to be reopened is to edit the question.

So now I am curious as to what happens to a closed question when it is edited? 
I looked at the list of all the "Questions that may already have your answer" and the only one I found was [What happens to close flags after an edit has occurred](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300060/what-happens-to-close-flags-after-an-edit-has-occurred). That question was about a specific case - the OP put a close flag on a question and then the question was edited before enough close flags had accumulated.

Let me be clear - I want to know exactly - what queue does it enter and what has to happen for the question to be considered for reopening? I did poke around the review queues that I can access and it does not seem likely that the question will show up there. Based on the answers I received on the question I asked a couple of weeks ago - the question should get reviewed by somebody.

I am curious because if the question goes through the review process and remains closed I would then like to learn how to challenge that result.

There is a dup flag on my question - my question is not a duplicate of [Which edits push closed questions to the reopen review queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256567/which-edits-push-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue)  for one reason - the question I edited was not pushed to the review queue based on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078)

I think the correct answer to my question is that my edit did not cause the question to be entered into any review queue.  I am still not sure though so I am waiting.

Comment: Probably the fastest thing you could have done to get it reopened is mention it favorably in the meta, like you have.  There are already 4 reopen votes on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Editing a closed question will normally push it to the reopen queue, unless the question has been closed [more than five days ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078). In this case, a real reopen vote by a >3k-user will be needed, *unless* the 'sufficiently popular' rule is still in place – this question would qualify for that, I guess. But I tested this on a similar question, and it was *not* put in the reopen queue.

Your edit has at least provided the question with a real example, making it a lot more clear. It *could* still qualify as 'too broad', but I guess it's worthwhile to have a question like this on the site. I voted to reopen it; let's see what the community will make of it.

Comment: That is interesting - one of the foci of the response to my previous Meta question was that my edit would start the chain of events to lead the question being reopened