# Are we dupevoting meta questions about post bans too quickly?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, meta, post-ban

I have been around Meta.SO for a while and one of the things that I have noticed is that the community is *very* quick to dupevote questions about getting out of post bans (question bans and answer bans) to point to the "wall of text" question [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). In many cases, such as [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340269/what-can-i-do-about-neutral-reactions-to-specialist-questions) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325880/why-hasnt-the-question-ban-on-my-account-lifted-after-6-months), the question poster acknowledges the "wall of text" post ban question but indicates that they are seeking *more specific* guidance about *their own situation* and/or they are seeking more information about the ban that is *not* provided in that question.

Should we be so quick to mark these questions as duplicates? I can see that there could be a valid pedagogical reason to dupevote these - i.e. to force users to figure things out for themselves, but that seems to me to be a passive-aggressive strategy, as if we were to start closing all main site Stack Overflow posts about [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) syntax with the argument that everything one needs to know about C is already available in [K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) and/or the ANSI C standard document, and anyone too lazy to read, interpret, synthesize, and implement those documents is unworthy of help.

In some cases, an argument has been made that the "wall of text" question is literally *the entirety of the public body of knowledge about post bans*. If this is the case, then it makes sense for questions seeking information about post bans that is *not* in the document to *stay open*, waiting for the day when someone will come along with a helpful answer.

This is *not* a question about post bans themselves or how to get out of them - only a question about how we should handle questions *about them*.

Comment: If their question is not a dupe then they need to really explain how the target does not answer their question.  That will kick it into the reopen queue.

Comment: @NathanOliver people do do that, and their questions are rarely, if ever, reopened. Can you point to an example of an open question on how to get out of a post ban that is *not* a duplicate of the wall of text question?

Comment: Probably not because the wall of text target has everything they need to do.

Comment: any post that mentions ban but doesn't refer that canonical question, I would vote dupe in a heartbeat. I would abstain of dupe vote only if asker refers the canonical question and provides compelling explanation of how it didn't suffice to address their specific issue. Neither of your examples had that, and the first one ("specialist") seems to fail at explaining the difference after it was closed

Comment: @NathanOliver are you sure? Isn't that like saying that we don't need teachers any more - just give kids copies of all the textbooks and they can read them at home and thereby become educated? What if someone *doesn't understand* how the material applies to them and needs *further assistance*?

Comment: @RobertColumbia Not only do they need to explain, but the explanation needs to be convincing. For instance, "my question is not a dupe because the answers on the other question did not help me" is not *convincing*. There's also the fact that people do dig themselves into holes from which *we* cannot dig them out. If the advice in the canonical is not actually helping them, *we* cannot invent new ways to dig them out of their hole.

Comment: To the downvoters: Are you downvoting because you disagree with my thoughts or because my question is of low quality? This is [not a feature-request post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: @RobertColumbia Votes on meta often express disagreement. Yes, there's some verbiage about voting for disagreement being the province of feature requests but, as a practical matter, that verbiage is not constraining how people vote on meta. The reality of it is that people do vote on meta to express disagreement, feature request or not.

Comment: No it is not like saying we don't need teachers.  The dupe is asking them to read a chapter and understand how it applies to their current situation.  Were not throwing a full text book at them.  I have yet to see a post asking about the post ban that is not covered in the answer on the post ban canonical.

Comment: I'd imagine the downvotes are meant to say: "No, we are not dupevoting meta questions about post bans too quickly"

Comment: @NathanOliver the canonical is missing some information about how to find your (recently) deleted questions. I have raised a mod flag (earlier today) to have the question temporarily unlocked in order to edit this in.

Comment: @Glorfindel That would be a nice addition.  They could find that by searching but we might as well tell them about it in there since it is tightly coupled.

Comment: Yeah, trust me, explaining that 10 times to different users gets tiresome rather quickly.

Answer (score 28):

The reason we close them as duplicates is because they are duplicates.

More to the point—so far, in every case, the person has been hiding deleted posts that contributed to the ban. They pretend to be the hapless victim of an unfair ban and not know what the problem is, but either they're lying or they haven't actually bothered to read and understand the question to which they've been pointed countless times. In either case, it hardly seems unjustified to point them to it again. If they can't read and understand that, they really have no hope of ever getting out of the ban. We have a certain minimum expectation of competence for participation here. I hope that comes as no surprise.

There is also a certain degree of push-back because people who have hit a post ban have already wasted a significant amount of the community's time, and now they're coming to Meta to whine about it and waste even more of our time. This is doubly worse if they're whining about it *without having read the information we provided*. Triply worse if they're whining about it in a deceptive manner. You might say that this is unfair. I might agree, if the post bans were easy to trip and there were lots of false positives (*cough* review audits *cough*), but they simply are not.

If someone truly doesn't understand what the text is trying to tell them, or they really think that their issue is an exception, they can either include that information from the outset in the question, or edit it in after it has been closed as a duplicate of the canonical question. That editing will place it into the reopen queue, where users will evaluate whether or not it should be reopened. Again, 99% of the time, it does not merit reopening because the edit continues to be as deceptive or information-poor as the original.

It doesn't do us any good to have answers on dozens of questions repeating ourselves. The logic is the same as for closing any other duplicate—keep all of the information in one place.

Your analogy that it is like closing a C question as a duplicate of K&R is ridiculous on any number of levels. The better analogy for Meta questions about post bans is that the person didn't bother to read the error message spit out by the compiler.

---

This is a bit tangential to your question, but the *smart* way for someone to handle a post ban would be to read the provided information and, armed with that knowledge, go back and try to edit some of their old, poorly-received contributions. If they have *specific questions* about how to do that, then they are welcome to bring those to Meta. I will admit that sometimes we are not as receptive to those types of questions as we should be (can't find the relevant prior discussions at the moment), but this is the way it should be working.

There is otherwise no way that *the community* can help these users with improving their standing. It can't happen in the "why am I post-banned?" question, because diamond-moderator privileges are required to view someone's deleted posts—very likely the ones that will indicate the root of the problems. If you aren't up-front about them, we can't help you. So the solution is to be up-front about them.

Note that this is not altogether different from the smart way to ask questions on Stack Overflow. You don't dump a task or requirement, and expect people to write code that implements it for you. Rather, you ask specific questions about the aspects of the task that you are struggling with.

Comment: "[...] in every case, the person has been hiding deleted posts that contributed to the ban" -- [Today's example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341055/2751851).

Comment: *I will admit that sometimes we are not as receptive to those types of questions as we should be (can't find the relevant prior discussions at the moment)* There's one here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268779/can-we-make-this-meta-site-work-for-mentoring/268788#268788

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327832/questions-in-meta-should-not-be-closed-as-duplicates-when-they-ask-about-specifi, and the one I originally thought of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336622/can-we-talk-about-the-reviewing-culture-here-on-meta

Comment: Thanks for the links, @BSMP. Two of those were among the ones I had in mind, but couldn't find. I would swear that Pekka started a discussion about this that received some really good responses, but I couldn't find it it in his recent questions. Maybe I'm just remembering some of his answers.