# Is there a better mediation method to help lift their question ban?

Tags: support, edits, asking-questions, deleted-questions, post-ban

I will not sugar coat it, I am question banned.
I have **1** downvoted question. I have gone to the suggestions page on how to get the ban lifted and followed the steps. Luckily I only have 6 questions. I have reworded them, reworded the titles, cleaned up a bunch of typos and issues and the system still sees me as question banned.

I feel as though there could be a better way for the system to instruct users like myself on how to understand and lift the question ban. I also understand that deleted questions also count into the system. I don't think I have any deleted questions but even if I did how would I be able to edit them or rectify them if I cannot see them?

This seems to put the user account into such a negative state that it cannot come out of. I have looked through the question ban questions as well as suggestion questions for recourse but have not found answer to the "How to edit Deleted Questions" question either on further helping to bring your account into good standing.

Is it possible to edit Deleted questions? After rewording, cleaning and organizing questions with no vote actions or feedback what is the users' next form of recourse?

Comment: You're asking like 5 different questions here.  You should be asking one question per question, not 5 different questions.

Comment: You could always just wait 6 months and ask a really good question. Might have to repeat a few times though.

Comment: You say you've edited those questions, but have they attracted any upvotes? You may be pleased by them, but until there's measurable agreement from others the system has no reason to allow you to ask again.

Comment: In regards to 1 downvoted question - that doesn't include all the **deleted** questions. Which all count, and there are a few with downvotes there.

Comment: Servy I can certainly separate this post into multiple questions if you like. Kevin B my last question was in April of 2014 so the 6 months does not cancel the ban. Whenever I try to ask a question I am met with the ban message. I do not believe the 6 month time limiter works. jonrsharpe I have edited all the questions multiple times and have attracted no upvotes. I do not believe it is even looked at by those looking at such an old question as something to upvote when most of the content is no longer valid do to code or standards changing. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: It should also be noted that questions with a score of 0 are not considered positive either. Looking at your non deleted questions you have 6 questions with a combined total score of 1.

Comment: @Oded that was part of the question initially.I do not have any deleted questions. But if one does have a deleted question with down vote how are they to edit that to come back to good standing? I have 1 downvote twice question but other than that my others have upvotes and multiple views and comments.

Comment: @JukEboX Your last question was in march of 2015, not april 2014, and if you're still banned, then it's because you have newer deleted questions.

Comment: You have deleted questions. I can see them, as a developer here. A few of them have downvotes on them.

Comment: @Oded how am I to rectify the deleted question then? I cannot edit them. Also my account on my end shows no deleted questions. So I guess the answer is as you have suggested below is to just comment on questions and fix people formatting, syntax, spelling, etc? If that is the question then why is this not added to the guide for getting your account in good standing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304628/copyright-web-system http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056071/show-php-week-table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131451/php-pdo-insert-using-colon-array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726507/querying-event-logs-with-xml-time-period http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984396/debug-log-not-showing-issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40306738/pdo-connection-creation-causes-server-500-error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40312530/php-server-500-error-on-post-of-pulldown - there you go.

Comment: @KevinL I agree voting fraud is not correct but I also don't think letting the community vote on what is valid is either some times. There are a lot of people in different specialties that would say your questions on their specific topic is juvenile or ridiculous so they down vote it simply because they are learning the code or something to that effect. I can say with a certainty I have fallen victim to that before as well.

Comment: I was going to suggest a different meditation method, but then I realized that wasn't what you were asking about.

Comment: @Oded I thank you very much. I will get to editing them. Hopefully they will get some upvotes to get unbanned. I do continue to pose the question though. If one cannot edit their deleted questions are they to troll other posts for things to edit or comment? And why hasn't that information been added to the help post?

Comment: @Oded Also since these questions are deleted by the community, if I edit them will the system notice the edits or do they need to be undeleted?

Comment: @JukEboX keep in mind that a couple of those questions are really broad and some are even off-topic. No editing will fix that.

Comment: Not all of them were deleted by the community, some were by you. Edits will put the questions in the reopen queue for community reopening (though you should be able to undelete the ones you deleted yourself).

Comment: @rene then those questions should probably remain dead.

Comment: @Oded Ok thanks. I will edit those that are mine as long as they still have merit. If a user wanted to undelete any of their own questions and it does not show up in their deleted questions, how would they get to them?

Comment: Asking for a list of them from moderator would be the only way (excepting those deleted in the last 60 days - there's a link at the bottom of the questions tab of your profile).

Comment: I posted a suggestion on one of your questions last night and it looks like the question is now gone. Did you delete it? I was trying to help you improve the question.

Comment: @RobertColumbia it was deleted by the "community" so it wasn't me that deleted it. Also someone downvoted the question which in turn has not made it frustratingly annoying that I can't ask questions again. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @JukEboX would you like to request that a mod undelete it? IMHO the question still needs some work but it is salvageable.

Comment: @RobertColumbia that would be helpful. I can try and edit it AGAIN.

Comment: When you visit the question, does it give you the option to undelete?

Comment: @RobertColumbia for most of them, no.

Comment: So my previous downvoted question have been deleted and are not relevant to resurrect. So that seems I have dug this account into a hole. Remediation methods have been fruitless. I can rewrite, organize and clean questions of the ones that are currently active as much as I want but they won't get attention to get upvoted to get me into good standing.

So is my only recourse now to troll the new questions to fix and clean others questions or office "helpful" comments?

Answer (score 10):

Keep improving *the site*, not just your previous contributions to it.

Answer things, suggest edits to posts (improve formatting, grammar, syntax, spelling etc...).

The more of these you do, the closer you will be to getting out of the ban.

Comment: according to the ban you cannot post questions OR answers. So answering questions is not an option. Also trolling to edits for grammer, format, etc seems like those in the ban need to be constantly competing with everyone else on new questions to get their score up which seems ridiculous for the casual question asker.

Comment: Not correct. Your **question ban** means you cannot post **questions**. You can still post answers, unless you are in an answer ban too.

Comment: @JukEboX you have a great point. Casual askers don't have a hidden agenda, we dont have time to keep up with rules. We ask something simple that then for some reason mods just delete or revise on us. Almost feels like this site was designed to stalk people and if not to become a stalker to succeed.

Comment: @DeerSpotter isn't that a bit the world up-side down? So casual askers don't have to time to keep up with the rules but in the mean time it is expected that I answer all that badly researched, unclear mud? Isn't it impolite when you're somewhere new to simply assume there are no rules?

Comment: @rene  I think what DeerSpotter is trying to say is that casual askers ask a question at that time and walk away after asking and don't take the time to double/triple check with the guidelines of the board for a  perfect question. And even if they did then who would be able to edit their question to get a better meta score or help get someone out of the ban?

Comment: @rene i never said to circumvent the rules, only to assume the that rules arent here to help and thus becasue of those rules mods should realize that new users have no chance.

Comment: @DeerSpotter we disagree there, we have the [tour], the [help], [meta-tag:faq] at best you missed a couple of chances ...

Comment: @rene if you see the downvotes on my answer below, believe when i tell you. No answer gets downvoted so hard like that unless it speaks volume of truth. Im not some scumbag idiot, you can see on my profile i know stuff. i deserve to be part of the community just like you. You guys are downvoting the answer i left because you guys have no real answer to the fellow above.

Comment: @DeerSpotter - or perhaps if it is completely off-base. Funny you don't seem to be able to consider that your POV is wrong.

Comment: @DeerSpotter I'm fairly certain that your answer is heavily downvoted because it doesn't actually attempt to provide a solution (unless you call suggesting the user break the rules to get out of jail a solution), and is mostly just a "me too" comment posted as an answer. It is also a rant which intends to insult a great many users who spend a lot of volunteer time keeping this site clean and useful.

Comment: @DeerSpotter I know nothing. And I and others helped the OP with answers and comments, useful info for an OP that makes an honest attempt to learn from their mistakes. And I do that day in, day out, week in, week out, year in, year out. But I simply don't respond well to whining.

Comment: @TinyGiant whats breaking the rules when you answer someones question? Especially if it is right? SHOW me where i would be breaking the rules? IF i go to the unanswered and actually answer stuff instead of deleting the questions, imagine that maybe once this wont be a heavily debated topic.

Comment: you all should be ashamed of yourselfs, please remember OP's post, and remember my question was inline of the post. I did my research and posted a response in the best way that could actually help the user. Nobody else posted a actual solution, because you're all afraid of downvotes.

Comment: [*"**Don't answer questions** that have already been answered elsewhere. Yeah, you might earn a couple of points of reputation, but, because you are duplicating content, you are actually making the internet worse. Why? Because that answer might be true today, but as technology changes, it might not be true tomorrow."*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) This isn't a heavily debated topic. Everyone else seems to be in agreement. You can't fathom that you might be wrong, that's why it seems heavily debated to you. @DeerSpotter

Comment: @TinyGiant im sorry if i dont believe in deleting a question is right. Especially when there is a huge button staring at new users "Ask Question"

Comment: Trust me, the community is very much trying to get that button moved to a different place. Deletion, closure, up and down votes, editing, etc. are all appropriate in given circumstances, and inappropriate in others. You're being far to vague with your arguments for them to be of any value. It's up to you to read the manual before attempting to use a product or service, and if you don't then the consequences are on you.

Comment: "Almost feels like this site was designed to stalk people and if not to become a stalker to succeed. – DeerSpotter" Anyone else see the irony in this? No? Just me? OK...

Comment: @DeerSpotter What do you mean by "stalking"? I feel like I understand the gist of what you're trying to say, but I really don't understand that choice of words.

Comment: " is that casual askers ask a question at that time and walk away after asking and don't take the time to double/triple check with the guidelines of the board for a perfect question" - and we should not by any means reward this, because such conduct is antithetical to the goals of the site. "mods should realize that new users have no chance." Many, but certainly not all, new users "have no chance" - because they fundamentally want Stack Overflow to be something that it is not. People who want a help desk should seek one, not try to change how non-help-desk sites work so they become help desks.

Comment: "im sorry if i dont believe in deleting a question is right. Especially when there is a huge button staring at new users "Ask Question"" - this is actually a complete non sequitur. Along similar lines: Supermarkets exist. This is not a reason to buy whatever food you like and then keep it lying around the house if and when it goes moldy.