# What happens to suggested edits if a question is closed?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, closed-questions

Are they still part of the normal queue or are they rejected?

Comment: Related: [Which edits push closed questions to the reopen review queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256567/1364007) and [What happens to a closed question when it is edited?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327692/1364007).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They'll stay there as suggested edits when a question is put *on-hold*.
Also deletion of a question won't automatically *reject* your edits. But then it would disappear in the *Edit Review Queue*.

Comment: so what exactly happens when a question is removed as a duplicate? does that mean it's put on hold?

Comment: @alec935 It's the same as _on-hold_ state, yes.

Comment: To clarify: Deleting a question with a pending suggested edit *deletes* the suggested edit. It's as if it never existed. For closed questions, as you said, there is no change. The edit is still pending and awaiting review.