# Does a previous flag now count as declined when a post gets edited to a good condition?

Tags: support, edits, flags

What would happen if someone flags a question because it is unclear what the author is asking, but the question gets well edited before it is reviewed, so it's clear now what the author is asking.

Would this count as a declined flag for the user who had flagged the question?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**First, the practical part:**
If you notice that a post that you flagged has been improved, you can retract the flag. Click the "flag" button and choose "Retract Flag" in the flagging dialog.

**On to the question:**
If the flag is handled before you are able to retract it - well, you could very well get the flag declined. It happens.

When you flag a post, it will be entered into a review queue. Here, other users who have the "review" privilege will see the post *as it is when they start the review*. So if it was edited before a reviewer sees it... the reviewer will see the edited post. In the example of a formerly unclear question, they will hopefully conclude that the question is now clear.

As user That1Guy [points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344740/what-happens-if-a-question-gets-edited-after-getting-flagged-for-being-unclear?cb=1#comment452700_344745), a post can also be edited while in the review queue, and this may lead to the post being removed from the review queue. In this case (as Nathan Tuggy [points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344740/what-happens-if-a-question-gets-edited-after-getting-flagged-for-being-unclear?cb=1#comment452847_344745)), this should lead to the flag being "disputed".

All of this may seem a little unfair to flaggers. But there is no point in asking reviewers to review a post as it was before it was edited - the former version of the post is mostly irrelevant to Q&A, so asking people to judge it is a waste of everybody's time and effort. Reviewers judge the post *as it is now*, because that is the version that is active on the site.

If enough reviewers vote that the post is OK, the flag will be declined.
If there is sufficient disagreement, the flag will be disputed.

Comment: I can't find a canonical post, but I distinctly remember someone somewhere saying an (approved) edit to a question will dispute flags of this type. Perhaps this is no longer true? Or maybe I've got my wires crossed somewhere.

Comment: @That1Guy Now that you mention it,  IIRC edits can take a post out of the LQ queue. Which would lead the flag to be disputed or declined.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: An edit that removes a post from LQP will never decline a flag, IIRC, just dispute it.

Comment: So... we can retract flags!!! I see that it has been possible at least since last september, but I was completely unaware of this feature. I wonder if they announced it with a featured post...

Comment: If a post is edited in the queue, the flag is marked helpful, or at least that has been the case as far as I can remember. If something has changed recently to now dispute such flags instead of marking them helpful, that's news to me

Comment: Just a quick heads up: [If all 3 reviewers respond with "Looks OK", the post will appear as disputed](https://imgur.com/a/jytoa). The only way to receive a "declined" flag is if a diamond moderator intervenes, and reviews as "Looks OK". Additionally: If it's edited out of the queue, it will result in Helpful.