# Should I also keep checking for any updates in all the posts that I've flagged?

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags

A few days back I flagged an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48664863/5349542) as **NOT AN ANSWER** while Reviewing Late Answers, as it seemed to be a non-answer type of post. And I forgot about it.

Today, I am seeing that flag in **disputed section** (It was rejected). I revisited the question and I noticed it has been modified and now, seemingly it qualifies as an answer.

- So, should I also keep an eye for any changes in all the 50ish post I have flagged for any future changes?
- How does a flag which is rejected as **disputed** affects me? Is it bad?

Comment: Hard to imagine a valid reason to do this.  You flagged the post instead of taking care of it yourself, now somebody else gets the job done.  Whether or not they did is not interesting.  I suppose you can check if you want to but you'll surely quickly get bored with it.

Comment: @HansPassant option to _edit_ was not present.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344740/what-happens-if-a-question-gets-edited-after-getting-flagged-for-being-unclear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, should I also keep an eye for any changes in all the 50ish post I have flagged for any future changes?

Yes, this is *preferable*. Given that we now have an option to retract flags, it is better if you keep an eye on your flags and retract them when their purpose is met. In this way the flag will be removed from the queue. (But I do not mention that you *have* to do it)

Generally speaking, the review queue cannot mark flags as helpful. If a Non answer was later edited by the Original Poster and made into an answer then it can either be:

- disputed by the community after it has received enough "Looks OK" votes in the queue
- cleared by a moderator as helpful, if they see that the answer is now worthy of not being deleted.

The community users cannot mark your flag as helpful, after it was edited. If they need to do so, then they'll need to "Recommend Delete", mark your flag as helpful and then undelete it.

In that particular case, that answer does not qualify for a Not an answer flag. See [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer). So, I can tell you that you were quite lucky that a moderator did not see your flag. Else it would have been a clear decline. Kindly re-read that meta post about flagging answers as NAA, and take care the next time

> How does a flag which is rejected as disputed affects me? Is it bad?

It does not affect you in any way, it is not bad. 
From [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag)

> Disputed flags are considered neither helpful nor declined, regardless of the action taken in response to them. They do not affect a user's daily flag count and don't count toward flag bans.

---

There is a [community project](https://stackapps.com/questions/7337/generic-bot-a-moderation-chatbot), that tracks all the edits on a flagged posts, and reports them to the flagger.

Comment: What do you mean by _then they'll need to "Recommend Delete"_ ?

Comment: @BlackBeard, I'm just telling about a very far fetched work around. For normal users to mark others flags as helpful, they'll need to delete the post and then undelete. In the LQPQ, there is an option called "Recommend Delete", which adds one vote towards deleting the answer.

Comment: So, I should not flag a post which seems more like a comment than answer as a NAA?

Comment: No you shouldn't. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer