# Edit Questions and the Ban

Tags: support, edit-ban

I was wondering how I should edit the post because because I recently was banned.

Usually the people writes so:
*blablablablabala 2kg of text* without jump lines and also they do not clarify their ideas

When I'm reading the text, if **I see a idea in bold** sure could understand very easy.

I simply **add** jump of lines, bold and the `` ` `` for the code.
Then usually I put titles as, `reading improvement or self + add code`.

Now I've tried to edit but says **You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits - please review your edit history.**

---

I have 35 approved edit of 45

see by yourself https://regex101.com/r/aJ6iV2/1

I just try to help users so that they can answer their question. **I would like know what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: First, you can just link to [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4941927/milor123?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) instead of regex101. Second, you can view the reason your suggested edits were rejected yourself. You're not really improving posts, just marking them up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing Ban, But Few Rejected Edits?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299808/editing-ban-but-few-rejected-edits) or [Why am I temporarily banned from suggesting edits?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297351/why-am-i-temporarily-banned-from-suggesting-edits)

Comment: Read through : [complete rate-limit guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide/164900#164900)

Comment: Your post by itself is already difficult to read. There's **no** reason to *randomly* format `your` text, because when ***everything*** is emphasised, *nothing* is `emphasised`.

Comment: You are grossly misusing bold text, italic text and code markup.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your edits are doing nothing for the readability or quality of the posts you edit. You seem to emphasise random parts of the text, making the entire thing harder to read and quite frankly quite a bit of an eyesore. In addition to this, you forget crucial things in your edits, such as editing out fluff like "Thanks in advance" and somesuch similar things.

Italic and bold text is supposed to be used *sparingly* and only if it actually improves the readability of the post you are editing. And blindly adding code markup to filenames (?) is not great either.

Generally speaking, I think way too many of your edits were actually approved, and now it will take someone else some time of getting rid of your unnecessary code tagging and over emphasising of random sentences in the post.

Comment: Ok dude, sorry. I thought could help with reading.  Sorry for the inconveniences. Thank you very much